# different theme for landscape and portrait mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode4

Let me explain what I am creating and it will be nice if someone could tell me a better approach.

I am creating an app that supports all orientations. The app is like a power point presentation with several slides with several images and basic functionality in each slide. the functionality is very simple such as showing an image or moving an image when a button is pressed for example. So creating the app is not the problem. Since this app has to support all orientations when the device enters portrait mode I need to move the content in order to make it fit for the portrait orientation. And I would have to do the same thing if it enters landscape mode. Because there is so much content in every slide I need to change the content very much when changing orientation. so an image in portrait mode might have cords (20,5) and on landscape mode that image will have totally different coordinates.

So is there a way that I can set the IBOutlets have specific cords on landscape and specific cords on portrait with xcode. It takes me forever to store the cords of every IBOutlet in an array since I have so many IBOutles in each slide. I have to store the CGPoints in an array with the cords of IBOutlets in landscape and portrait mode and then if the device enters landsape mode set it's center equal to the array elemets. THIS IS SIMPLE BUT IT TAKES FOREVER!

Moreover I am creating many xib files and treat each xib as a different slide in my app.

Comment: [This link][1] may be of some help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498558/best-way-to-change-xib-files-based-on-rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you are saying, you need two xibs for each "slide". One that describes the portrait orientation, and one that describes the landscape orientation.