# iOS: AutoRotating between NIBs

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

My universal app is a single full screen view. Pressing a button flips to reveal a settings page:

```
- (void) showSettings
{
FlipsideViewController * flipsideVC = [FlipsideViewController alloc];

NSString * settingsNib;
if ( isIPad() )
    settingsNib = isCurrentlyPortrait() ? @"settings_iPad_portrait" : @"settings_iPad_landscape";
else
     settingsNib = @"settings_iPhone";

[flipsideVC initWithNibName: settingsNib
                     bundle: nil ];

flipsideVC.delegatePointingToMainVC = self;

flipsideVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController: flipsideVC 
                        animated: YES ];

[flipsideVC release];
}
```

and the settings page invokes the delegate method:  I recreate the main view in light of the changed settings,  and flip back.

```
- (void) settingsDidQuit:(FlipsideViewController *) flipsideVC 
{
[self createOrRecreateWheelView];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}
```

But what if the user rotates the iPad on the settings page? Apple decrees that my app must handle this. But how to do this?   can I dynamically load a new XIB for the settings page?

I can't see a way to do that, so my attempted solution is to catch the rotation within the settings view, ...

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) oldInterfaceOrientation 
{
[self.delegatePointingToMainVC settingsOrientationChanged]; 
}
```

...and call back to the main view controller, which dissolves the settings view controller and recreates it in light of the current orientation.

```
- (void) settingsOrientationChanged
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
[self showSettings];
}
```

There is a trivial problem straight away -- didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation  gets triggered automatically when the settings page loads.   I can prevent this  by setting a boolean to false in init,  and  modifying thus:

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) oldInterfaceOrientation 
{
if (initialized)
    [self.delegatePointingToMainVC settingsOrientationChanged]; 

initialized = true;
}
```

problem with this approach is that I navigate to the settings page,  rotate the device,  and it momentarily shows the correct settings page, before flicking back to my main view.

I think there is a threading problem here.  But maybe my whole approach is wrong. Can somebody suggest a better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496554/easiest-way-to-support-multiple-orientations-how-do-i-load-a-custom-nib-when-the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. You want the settings view (loaded from NIB) to autorotate? You should just return YES for the orientation you want the autorotation to be performed in the *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:* and set the autoresizing mask of the views inside the XIB accordingly to your needs.

There's no need to call back the main view controller and tell him to push a new settings view controller. The rotation behavior of the views is determined by the autoresizing mask properties of each view and the implementation of *shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:* method of the associated view controller and just that. If want to do more advanced animations, though, you can set up and manage them in the *willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:* and *didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:* methods.

Comment: Thanks -- this works perfectly for my situation,  as my actual layout design doesn't change when I turn the device -- only the proportions and spacing.