# Best way to change UIViewController view NIB programmatically

Tags: interface-builder, ipad, orientation, rotation

I have this iPad application with different NIBs and views.
Each view has two NIBs, one for potrait orientation and one for landscape, so i'm searching for a method to programmatically switch NIB for a given UIViewController .

Right now i have this function that i'm using in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method of each controller :

```
void UIHandleRotation( UIViewController *controller, NSString *nibName, UIInterfaceOrientation orientation, BOOL transform ){
    double angle = 0.0;

    if( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) {
        angle = PI * 2 /* 360° */;
    } 
    else if( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ){
        angle   = PI + PI/2 /* 270 ° */;
        // Each landscape nib is [nib-name]L
        nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@L", nibName];
    }    

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:controller options:nil];
    if( transform ) {
        controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( angle );
    } 
}
```

But it's giving me strange behaviour (ui controls position messed, the outlets are not associated as in interface builder, and so forth).

Am i doing something wrong or there's just a better way to implement this ?
Thanks

NOTE: I'm not using a navigation controller, so i can't use this solution [Easiest way to support multiple orientations? How do I load a custom NIB when the application is in Landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496554/easiest-way-to-support-multiple-orientations-how-do-i-load-a-custom-nib-when-the/2496719#2496719)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't switch nibs, you should switch controllers.

See this answer for: [Easiest Way to Support Multiple Orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496554/easiest-way-to-support-multiple-orientations-how-do-i-load-a-custom-nib-when-the/2496719#2496719)

Comment: See the note i've just added.

Comment: You can use a navigation controller and its the easiest way to do this. You don't have to expose the navigation controller in the interface. The example I linked to does not do so. The user cannot tell a navigation controller is being used.

Answer (score 3):

You should use only one NIB with two views, one for portrait(potraitView) with frame(0,0,768, 1024)and 
another for landscape(landScapeView) with frame(0,0,1024, 768).
And set your controls in both views (potraitView and landScapeView) according to your requirements.

and after this you can set your views according to device orientation as-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
{
landScapeView.hidden = YES;
portraitView.hidden = NO;

}

else{

landScapeView.hidden = NO;
portraitView.hidden = YES;

}
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Hi,

As I think you want to know, when the view loads, what is the default orientation, and How I can load the view according to this orientation.
If this question is same as you are asking, then the answes is-

When you run your application and the same class view loads, then - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
method is called automatically. Then it returns your device orientation, and sets your view according to this orientation(using the same code as described above).
I think you need not to do more.

Comment: How do i exactly handle the default view outlet then? Could you please edit your post and explain me the whole views creation/binding to IB?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have one view per nib, so your UIViewController will have two UIViews. one for portrait, and one for landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use 2 nibs for the same view.You should use one nib for different orientations.You can handle the required controls programatically in the same method

willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Thanks.