# Keyboard appears in Landscape and ipad is in Portrait

Tags: objective-c, ios4

My keboard appears in landscape but the ipad is in portrait and when in landscape appears in landscape

I have 2 xibs and in the landscape xib have the code in viewDidLoad:

```
 CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    [self.view setTransform:rotate];
```

Comment: Some elaboration might be required to reach a possible solution.

Comment: has no code..when the ipad is in portrait the keyboard appears in landscape...no need more infos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in your question. you rotate your screen with your code.

```
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633); [self.view setTransform:rotate];
```

does exactly that. 1.57079633 is the same as M_PI/2, which is the same as 90°

delete the code or uncomment it like

```
// CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633); [self.view setTransform:rotate];
```

Comment: but If I do this, the xib appears in wrong orientation

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496554/easiest-way-to-support-multiple-orientations-how-do-i-load-a-custom-nib-when-th/2496719#2496719