# How to create separate UI for Landscape and Portrait?

Tags: ios, user-interface

Is there any good tutorial that shows how to create a UI like the one on iPhone's calculator? It looks to me that it has two different views in the same initial ViewController and they change according to the orientation of the iPhone.

[image: Landscape]    [image: Portrait]

Comment: A good place to start would be WWDC'16 presentations, particularly session 222, Making Apps Adaptive Part 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a project and publish it on GitHub for everyone wants to create a UI that responds exactly like the default iPhone calculator. The link for the project is https://github.com/FotiosTragopoulos/OrientationUI

Answer (score 0):

As dfd said in comment, you should watch WWDC presentation https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/222/. After that you can check that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533561/1189244

Answer (score 0):

You should be familiar with autolayout and size classes. This is good tutorial https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/